# Android Code : I am tring to pass string values from one page to another

Tags: android

Am not able to understand where is the issue in it and m not able to execute the application

n further line their is my code

CODE:
pass1:-

```
public class Pass1 extends Activity {

    EditText pno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
String pn=pno.getText().toString();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pass1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(pn.charAt(0)=='9' || pn.charAt(0)=='8' || pn.charAt(0)=='7')
            {
                if (pno.getText().toString().length()==10)
                {
                 Intent i= new Intent(Pass1.this, Pass2.class);
                        i.putExtra("phoneno", pn);
                                startActivity(i);                   
                }
        }
        else
            pno.setError("The entered number is invalid!!");


            }               
        });
    }
}
```

pass2:-

```
public class Pass2 extends Activity {

EditText codetxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

String ph=codetxt.getText().toString();

Button codebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        final String phn = i.getStringExtra("phoneno");


setContentView(R.layout.activity_pass2);
            codebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override


public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(ph.charAt(0)==phn.charAt(0) && ph.charAt(1)==phn.charAt(5) && ph.charAt(2)==phn.charAt(4) && ph.charAt(3)==phn.charAt(9))
                {
                    if( codetxt.getText().toString().length()==4)
                    {
                        //code.setError("right number");
                        Intent i=new Intent(Pass2.this,Pass3.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }
                else
                    codetxt.setError("Entered Code is wrong!"); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Does Pass2 not start? If it does start, what is the value of phn?

Comment: where is setContentView() method???

Answer (score 2):

Move this code

```
 EditText pno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
String pn=pno.getText().toString();
```

inside onCreate() after the setContentView() line. And similarly for Pass2

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

in Your case

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String phn = extras.getString("phoneno");
```

Comment: its been a failer on both the program

Answer (score 0):

you should use `findViewById()` after `setContentView()`

Comment: mai be i thnk thr is a linkin prob off pages